# I can't change any user settings with my login, why?

Tags: remote-desktop, users, settings

The account I'm using is the first account on the system and it can use the sudo command. But when I'm trying to change anything in the User Settings program nothing happens. I can change my own password but not the other user's which I have created. Could this be because of that I'm using a NX remote session to administrate the computer? Or is there any settings which I have forgotten to do?

Comment: What is the output of `tail -f ~/.xsession-errors` while you try to change another user's password?

Comment: I get: "(nautilus:3430): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed"

Comment: But it seems like I have a lot of errors here, many regarding: "(npviewer.bin:8454): Gdk-WARNING **: XID collision, trouble ahead." What does that mean?

Comment: The error only seems to occur when I'm connected through the nx-client. Otherwise it works. So I guess this is more of a Free-NX related bug :/

Comment: run `pkexec --user NAME gedit` in a terminal and post any output, perhaps PolicyKit is messed up.  Gedit won't actually start, but maybe it will give some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PolicyKit-based tools don't work over remote connections, as evidenced by the two following bugs:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit/+bug/230656

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit/+bug/614291

I'd suggest clicking the "this bug affects me too" link on the second one (since it is more generic than simply xdmcp, which is no longer supported by default) to get it higher on developers' radars.